# How to perform a paired T-test for multiple variables in R?

Tags: r

My figures are roughly as follows:

outcome paired ID variable A  variable B variable C ... ...variable 99
1          1   0.163928565 1.384097885 2.590867531    1.810971177
0          1   0.351326004 1.231992145 3.309521365    1.838901895
1          2   0.290323902 1.224666519 3.346976812    1.804317302
0          2   0.086592296 0.967414001 3.127342374    1.95104196
0          3   0.222788134 1.650655928 2.980752068    2.186048898
1          3   0.313679639 0.740220592 3.171875959    2.006938751
1          4   0.053655263 1.520590707 3.122244134    1.993673427
0          4   0.773468753 1.748194237 2.970937425    2.478458766
1          5   0.118214112 1.041165238 2.861498509    1.753158127
0          5   0.324957992 1.217722730 3.388696112    1.656588554
0          6   0.056653395 1.361329046 3.430776036    1.592871162
1          6   0.904333005 1.483637306 2.023881029    1.750633756

Each pair has two outcomes (disease or not). How do you use R to conduct paired T-test?

I have tried the for loop and the melt function to adjust the format and then the perform paired t test, but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first column of my data describes the two outcomes, the second column is the pair number, and the columns after that are all different indicators.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.